# Calling HTML coding in JavaScript function using Spring framework

Tags: java, html, spring

Can anyone tell me how can I call all my html coding using JavaScript in Spring framework without using any template engine such as Thymeleaf?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you have to create request mapping for that the HTML page.

```
@RequestMapping(value="/hello", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView product_save(){
    ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView();
    model.setViewName("hello"); // HTML page name
    return model;
}
```

Your hello.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>hello</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Welcome!</h1>        
    </body>
</html>
```

And your js

```
window.location = "hello";
```

Comment: Can you tell me the purpose of having ModelAndView method?

Comment: Model is hold the information which you want to display on the View.
Eg: ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView(); model.addObject("yourobject","yourmessage"); View is which file you are going to map.

Comment: yes that is according to MVC architecture. But in your code you have created a method called product_save. What is the purpose of that method?

Comment: I have made the code as a sample you can change anything you want

Comment: You don't get my question. But that's ok. Thanks for your responds

Answer (score 0):

What is purpose behind calling JS using spring-framework, any specific requirement. you can call JS methods and invoke this JS methods on body load while page rendering